# Where is the Windows SDK 11 installed by Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, winapi

On the Microsoft doc they say that debugging tools are included in the Windows SDK.

> Debugging Tools for Windows is included in the Windows Software Development Kit (SDK). To download the installer or an ISO image, see Windows 10 SDK on Windows Dev Center.

With a link to another page saying to install the Windows SDK 11, and that it can be installed through the Visual Studio 2019 Installer.
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-sdk/

> You can get the Windows SDK in two ways: install it from this page by selecting the download link or by selecting “Windows 11 SDK (10.0.22000)” in the optional components of the Visual Studio 2019 Installer.

Which I did (and also latest Windows SDK 10), but I cannot find the SDK 11 on my computer. They are supposed to be located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\` but there I only see the `10` and not `11`.
Even in the Windows SDK 10 there is no debugging tools as mentioned in [the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/getting-started-with-windbg).

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64

Comment: *windows 11* is only marketing name. internal this is still windows 10 with higher build number. `10.0.22000.0` and higher ..

Comment: Oh, ok thanks! So that means when I installed both 10 and 11, the 11 just overwrote the 10 I guess. But that's not an issue in my case.

Comment: No, it didn't "overwrite" anything. It got installed into its own directory, identified as `10.0.22000.0` (or higher). The internal version of Windows 11 is still `10.0`. That's not entirely new; the internal version of Windows 7 is `6.1`, and for Windows 8 is `6.2`. The SDK doesn't follow marketing names.

Comment: Indeed I have several subfolders inside `bin` and `Lib`, but there is only one `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10` that's why I was confused.